# how do i get the rank of a specific row in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, row, sql-order-by, rank

I tried to use this query to get the ranks of each vendr by their rating

```
SELECT vendorid, rating, RANK() over(ORDER BY rating DESC)ranking
FROM vendors
```

but I want to get the ranking of a specific vendor so I put the where clause like this:

```
SELECT vendorid, rating, RANK() over(ORDER BY rating DESC)ranking
FROM vendors
WHERE vendorid=1
```

but it returns a value of 1 in ranking even though it is not rank 1.
how should I fix this?

Comment: Make your ranking query a subquery and in the new main query filter by customer otherwise you are ranking your filtered results.

Answer (score 4):

In this case

```
SELECT 
    vendorid, rating, 
    RANK() OVER (ORDER BY rating DESC) ranking 
FROM 
    vendors 
WHERE 
    vendorid = 1
```

Rank is calculated after where, so after filtering, SQL Server will assign ranks and show rank for whatever values left

*How to fix this?*

Use subquery or cte like below.

```
;With cte as
(
    SELECT 
        vendorid, rating, 
        RANK() OVER (ORDER BY rating DESC) ranking 
    FROM 
        YOURTABLE
)
select * 
from cte 
where vendorid = 1
```

Comment: idk but cte thing did not work but thanks! though I found this solution:  'SELECT v.Vendorid, v.rating, v.ranking FROM  (SELECT vendorid, rating, RANK() over(ORDER BY rating DESC)ranking FROM vendors) v WHERE vendorid=1'

Comment: @patriza16:CTE Thing will work,replace vendors with your table